# ngOnInit not called after changing URL manually

Tags: angular, url, redirect, jwt, ngoninit

I have two types of users in my app : ADMIN and USER

I'm trying to secure the pages that only an admin can access, so I wrote this code to prevent a non-adming user from manually changing the URL to an Admin page:

```
ngOnInit() {

    console.log("************");

    if(!this.authService.isAdmin())
      {
        this.authService.logout();
        this.router.navigateByUrl('login');
      }

  }
```

The `ngOnInit()` hook is not triggered if URL for this component is entered manually and  the non-admin user is still able to use the page. However if the user lands on the page using router, the hook is triggered and the non-admin is logged out.

Comment: Please clarify your question. The relationship between the login URL and this code snippet is not explained. What is the specific piece of information you are hoping to acquire?

Comment: You should use Route Guards for this.

Comment: thank youu Route Guards did the job